# Setting Cmake Library paths without Editing CmakeLists

Tags: cmake

Goal: To set Cmake Paths without having to edit the CMakeLists.txt file.

In Linux, using `find_library()` in Cmake is enough to find a library installed with apt.

In Windows, Cmake is unable to find it automatically.

Note: Please treat sqlite3 as any library.

What is the proper method to set the library paths which cmake searches for my library files **without** having to edit CMakeLists?

Note: I have samlib compiled to a static library file and placed in some directory away from the project itself.

I have tried the following on Linux and Windows.

````
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(SampleProj VERSION 0.1.0)
find_library(samlib NAMES samplelib)

add_executable(SampleProj src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(SampleProj ${samlib})```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH`

> Semicolon-separated list of directories specifying a search path for the find_library() command. By default it is empty, it is intended to be set by the project. See also CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH and CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html

```sh
set CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64
cmake -H. -Bbuild -G "%CMAKE_GENERATOR%" "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=path_to_samlib"
```

Comment: Having to enter in paths for each library is painful, since they might be at different locations, how do you suggest I do the same for, say 10 libraries that I'm using in my project?

Comment: 1) look at the [search procedure of `find_package()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure), 2) try to use vcpkg to manage dependencies install, 3) install all your dependencies in the same build dir (see https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/cmake/dependencies/CMakeLists.txt.in)